# Get the item from a select list for the supplied index

Tags: jquery, listbox, selectlist

I have a select list that uses knockout data binding.

```
<select id="listBoxTwo"  size="10" data-bind="options: icdCodesForDxCodeSorterListBox2, value: listBoxTwoSelectedItem">
</select>
```

Using jquery how can I fetch an item from this select list for an index ?

Comment: Can we see the jquery that is failing for you?

Comment: The jquery is not failing for me. I could fetch the index using $("#listBoxTwo option:selected").index(). Now I want to fetch value from select list for above index.

Comment: I don't understand. If you can fetch the index, then why can't you fetch the value? Please post the `Javascript/jQuery/KnockoutJS` code that you are struggling with.

Comment: That's what I need. I am not sure how to fetch a value from a select list for an index.

Comment: Have you tried `$("#listBoxTwo option:selected").val()`? I don't understand your hang-ups if you don't show your code =]

Comment: I have not written any code other than that of fetching index which is $("#listBoxTwo option:selected").index(). The code that you wrote in previous comment will give me the currently selected item which I don't want. I want to fetch any item from the select list for which I am supplying the index.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with KnockoutJS and jQuery, which are also all simply Javascript libraries, you can accomplish this a number of ways. Determining the best way would require seeing code which you apparently don't have.

Therefore, I'll show you multiple ways (there are many more).

#### Plain-old Javascript (probably the best based on what you've said so far)

```
var listBoxTwo = document.getElementById('listBoxTwo');

//Get the selected value here.
var selectedIndex = listBoxTwo.selectedIndex;
var selectedValue = listBoxTwo.options[selectedIndex].value;
```

#### KnockoutJS Binding (I'm assuming this based on KnockoutJS's documentation)

```
function ListBoxTwoModel() {
    this.icdCodesForDxCodeSorterListBox2 = [
        //Your data here.
    ];
    this.listBoxTwoSelectedItem = ko.observable();
}
var listBoxTwoModel = new ListBoxTwoModel();
ko.applyBindings(listBoxTwoModel);

//Get the selected value here.
var selectedIndex = 10; //assuming you got the index somewhere else.
var selectedValue = listBoxTwoModel.icdCodesForDxCodeSorterListBox2[selectedIndex]; //Access your object's property here.
```

#### jQuery (just a bloated version of the first unless you are going to do other things with jQuery)

```
var listBoxTwo = $('#listBoxTwo');
var selectedIndex = listBoxTwo.find("option:selected").index();
var selectedValue = listBoxTwo[0].options[selectedIndex].value; //...
```

Comment: Since I am using knockout and the select list is bound to an observable, I just used vm.icdCodesForDxCodeSorterListBox2()[selectedIndex]. It was really simple. I am in jetlag today, that's why took so long to figure it out. Thanks for your help though.